# how to launch vscode live server as a task in launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I need to have vscode to launch vscode live server as a run configuration in launch.json, to be able to include its launch with other run configurations in a compound launch.

I have tried the `"Launch Extension"` of type `"pwa-extensionHost"` with several different arguments and runtimeexecutables, for example

```
    {
      "name": "Launch Extension",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-extensionHost",
      "runtimeExecutable": "liveserver"
    }
```

and

```
    {
      "name": "Launch Extension",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-extensionHost",
      "args": [
        "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
        "liveserver"
      ]
    }
```

but couldn't get it run.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, here is the solution for other's reference

create a task in `tasks.json`

```
{ 
  "label": "liveserver",
  "command": "${command:extension.liveServer.goOnline}"
}
```

prevent live server from launching the browser in `settings.json`

```
"liveServer.settings.NoBrowser": true
```

and add a `preLaunchTask` in `launch.json`

```
{
  "name": "launch live server",
  "type": "firefox",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "liveserver",
  "reAttach": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:5500",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

this way, when the debug config "launch live server" is run, it first launches live server (without browser) and then launches the debug browser.